What does querydsl operator exact ANY() in postgreSQL
Hi im using openfeign querydsl 5.6 and postgreSQL (psql) 16 with java 8. 
What does an operator exact to ANY() operator in psql for example:

select * from a left join b on a.cid = b.id

where (b.tags is not null AND 'some_tag' = ANY(b.tags);

Thanks in advance.

Currently, Im using array_position for an alternative:
Expressions.booleanTemplate(
    "(array_position({1}, {0}) is not null)",
    'some_tag', qB.tags
);

This expression seems to be conflicted with reserve keywords during build querydsl, so it's not working.
Expressions.booleanTemplate(
    "({1} = any({0}))",
    'some_tag', qB.tags
);


